# Download file from iCloud

Tags: xcode, icloud

I try to download a `.zip` file from iCloud to my local device with:

```
[fileMgr startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:fileURL error:nil];
```

But where is the file after download is completed ? I don't find it on the local device.

Thanks
Mirco

Answer (score 1):

The file is downloaded to: `~/Library/Mobile Documents/app_bundle_identifier/Documents/`